# Certificate in HiveMQ ClientData object

Tags: certificate, mqtt, hivemq

I'm currently digging into HiveMQ Plugin development. I developed custom functionality based on AfterLoginCallback. I configured a working TLS connection and I'm able to connect with the clients certificate.

```
mosquitto_pub.exe -t test -m "testMessage" --cafile myCertificates/hivemq-server-cert.pem  --cert myCertificates/sender.crt --key myCertificates/sender.key -p 8883"
```

However, when I debug the AfterLoginCallback code I find that my "ClientData -> certificate" is "null" throwing a IllegalStateExcpetion when accessed.

```
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional.get() cannot be called on an absent value
[INFO]  at com.google.common.base.Absent.get(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at mycode.hivemq.plugins.first_plugin.callbacks.AfterLoginCallbackTest.afterSuccessfulLogin(AfterLoginCallbackTest.java:33)
```

Can anyone explain please, why the certificate is null?

Thanks, 
Lomungo

Comment: Please make sure that you set client-authentication-mode to "OPTIONAL" or "REQUIRED" in your configuration file. An example can be found here: http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#client-cert-tls

Comment: yes, setting it from NONE to OPTIONAL or REQUIRED solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In the callback to check the credentials the `clientData` must be handled as  `ClientCredentialData`

Here is an example:

```
public class AuthorizationCallback implements OnAuthenticationCallback, OnAuthorizationCallback {

    @Override
    public Boolean checkCredentials(@NotNull final ClientCredentialsData clientData) throws AuthenticationException {

        //Throw out clients which didn't provide a client certificate
        if (!clientData.getCertificate().isPresent()) {
            log.debug("Client {} didn't provide a client certificate. Disconnecting client", clientData.getClientId());
            throw AuthenticationExceptions.WRONG_CERTIFICATE;
        }

        final Certificate certificate = clientData.getCertificate().get().certificate();
        ...
        }

}
```

Hope that helps!